# Is disabling Remote Desktop Services sufficient to protect a Windows device from the BlueKeep vulnerability?

Tags: windows, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities, remote-desktop

Microsoft ([and the NSA](https://betanews.com/2019/06/06/bluekeep-security-warning-nsa/)) have been urging Windows users and administrators to install patches to protect systems from the BlueKeep (CVE-2019-0708) vulnerability.

Is disabling Remote Desktop Services sufficient to protect any Windows device (any version) from the BlueKeep vulnerability?

Comment: Is there a reason patching isn't an option here?

Comment: @Steve Not my system.

Answer (score 4):

"... Remote Desktop Protocol ... Microsoft advises to disable it until the latest patches have been applied..."

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueKeep

Comment: So permanently disabling terminal service looks like an option.